# SqlDateTime overflow error when passing DateTime value to SQL database through webservice

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, datetime

Textview has a text with a date (`DateTime.Now.LocalTime`) that results in this format: `7/4/2016 3:32:40 PM`. I tried passing this through `DateTime time = Convert.ToDateTime(time.Text);` but gives me the SqlDateTime overflow error so I tried changing it into `DateTime time = DateTime.ParseExact(txt.Text, "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);` but gives me an incorrect format error. What could be the problem?

Here are my codes:

```
TextView txt = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.txt);
DateTime time = DateTime.ParseExact(txt.Text, "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

// to pass to webservice

userInfo.TimeStamp = time; // TimeStamp is DateTime type
```

Relevant codes:

```
private void DialogBox(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs) // this is for inserting the DateTime value into database
    {
        EmployeeDetails userInfo = new EmployeeDetails();
        DateTime now = DateTime.Now.ToLocalTime();
        TextView txt = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.txt);

        if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(request.Text))
        {
            Android.Support.V7.App.AlertDialog.Builder builder = new Android.Support.V7.App.AlertDialog.Builder(this, Resource.Style.AppCompatAlertDialogStyle);
            builder.SetTitle("Warning!");
            builder.SetIcon(Resource.Drawable.warning);
            builder.SetMessage("Please specify your comment or suggestion.");
            builder.SetPositiveButton("OK", (s, ev) => { });
            builder.Show();
        }
        else
        {
            txt.Text = now.ToString(); // this is for getting the value of passed datetime for next use
            userInfo.TimeStamp = now;
            _client.InsertToFeedbackTableAsync(userInfo);
        }
    }

private void ClientOnInsertToFeedbackTableCompleted(object sender, InsertToFeedbackTableCompletedEventArgs ea)
    {
        EmployeeDetails userInfo = new EmployeeDetails();
        TextView txt = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.txt);
        DateTime time = DateTime.ParseExact(txt.Text, "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

        string msg = null;

        if (ea.Error != null)
        {
            //blahblah
        }
        else if (ea.Cancelled)
        {
            //blahblah
        }
        else
        {
            msg = null;

            RunOnUiThread(() =>
            {                     
                userInfo.TimeStamp = time;                       

                _client.InsertToAnswersTableRequestAsync(userInfo);
            });
        }
    }

 private void ClientOnInsertToAnswersTableRequestCompleted(object sender, InsertToAnswersTableRequestCompletedEventArgs ea)
    {
        EmployeeDetails userInfo = new EmployeeDetails();
        TextView txt = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.txt);
        DateTime time = DateTime.ParseExact(txt.Text, "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        string msg = null;

        if (ea.Error != null)
        {
            //blahblah
        }
        else if (ea.Cancelled)
        {
            //blahblah
        }
        else
        { // blahblah}
```

My code in the webservice:

```
var fbID = from y in context.Feedbacks where y.timestamp == userInfo.TimeStamp select y.id; // where y.timestamp and userInfo.TimeStamp are DateTime
var fb_ID = fbID.FirstOrDefault();
int returnfbID = Convert.ToInt32(fb_ID);
```

Comment: How you pass date-time ?? as a string or DateTime ?

Comment: @DarshanPatel userInfo.TimeStamp is DateTime (and in the SQL database) so I passed the value as datetime as well.

Comment: Once you have something *in* a `DateTime`, it doesn't remember the format of the string from which it was brought into existence. It's just a `DateTime`. Provided you use parameters, everything should be fine. Common issues - taking a perfectly good `DateTime` and converting it into a string (which, again, won't use any previous formatting information) or accidentally passing a `default(DateTime)` for this or another parameter. Unfortunately, you're not showing the bits of code where we could see either of the above.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I just added the relevant codes. Please check.

Comment: Both Datetime.Parse & Convert.ToDateTime both work fine with the date string you are providing. Are you sure txt.Text is returning that string?

Comment: @GuyLowe I tried passing the value of txt.Text to setMessage of alertdialog to see if it isn't returning null, it shows as it is so I don't know why it gives the sqldatetime overflow and incorrect format error. I must have missed something on the code.

Answer (score 0):

Since your datetime values such as `7/4/2016 3:32:40 PM` can contain single digits, not necessarily 2 digits all times, you should use the format string `"M/d/yyyy h:m:s tt"` to `DateTime.ParseExact`.

Comment: I just tried this but gave me `SqlDateTime overflow. Must be between 1/1/1753 12:00:00 AM and 12/31/9999 11:59:59 PM`

Comment: The issue here is not with the parsing on the .NET side. Its to do with the datatype on the db side. Use data type datetime2 instead of datetime in the stored procedure/table.

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot edit the database since I have no owner rights.

Comment: Inserting datetime into the database works but why should it not work when I'm just selecting a value from the database based on the timestamp (on my code).

Comment: Please make sure before executing the db query whether you have a value in the timestamp field. If you haven't set it, since DateTime is a value type in .NET, it would get a default value of DateTime.MinValue (not null) which is 1/1/1, and that value is below the min value for a DateTime data type in SQL, and hence the error about the date time range.

Comment: The timestamp field values are from the datetime values I inserted on the DialogBox method. It works so I wonder why `7/4/2016` be read as lower than the minimum when it is obviously higher than `1/1/1753`.